# Using Protractor, can you find an element by id if that "element" is an angular component selector with an id attribute?

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm using the `MatTableModule` from Angular Material and when I display my table, I want to give each row an id. Which it looks like it is doing when I inspect the elements, I will see each `<mat-row>` contain an `id` attribute. But when I run my e2e tests, it says it cannot find the element by selector. Here is the table code:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="people" class="table">

            <!-- name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="tractor">
               <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-col-person"> Name</mat-header-cell>
               <mat-cell *matCellDef="let person" class="mat-cell-person"> {{person.name}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index;" [id]=" 'val'+ i" (click)="onRowSelected(row)"></mat-row>
         </mat-table>
```

`onRowSelected(row)` just navigates to the page where I then check if the element I need contains the selected person's name.

Every row will have an id of: `val#` such as: `val1`, `val2`, etc

And in my `person-summary.e2e-spec.ts` file which contains the testing code for this table I have:

```
// removing the beforeEach where I just navigate to the page
it('should navigate to the person summary screen when clicking on a row', ()=>{
        // navigates to a page about the user/person
        element(by.id('val1')).click();

        // wait for the next page to render and see if the element that contains the user's name appears
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('current-person'))), BROWSER_TIMEOUT);
        expect(element(by.id('current-person'))).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Then I get the following error:

```
× should navigate to the person summary screen when clicking on a row
      - Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="val1"])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('mat-table mat-row')
rows.get(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some waits before your inspect row, since the `mat-row` is updated dynamic . Not Sure why `id` is not picked. But you can use the below css locator below

`const ele = element.all(by.css('mat-table mat-row'));`

To access first row `ele.get(0);`

Hope it would resolves the issue.